# Finding whether a row exists in mysql or not using SELECT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, sql-insert

If there exists a row in the table FINES with the required value then I just want to update the fields
Else I want to add a new row in the table.

if (mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM fines WHERE SId='$sid' AND Semester='$sem')")>=1)

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE fines SET fines.TFine=fines.TFine+'$fine' WHERE SId='$sid' AND Semester='$sem'");
```

else

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO fines(SId, Semester, TFine, Flag) VAlUES('$sid','$sem', '$fine', 0)");
```

But the if condition is not working!! Please help

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in which updates a record already if it already exist while inserts if not.

First thing you need to do is to specify a `unique` constraint on a column or columns,

```
ALTER TABLE fines ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (SId, Semester)
```

once you have executed the statement, you could simply create a statement like this,

```
INSERT INTO fines(SId, Semester, TFine, Flag) 
VALUES ('$sid','$sem', '$fine', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TFine = TFine +  '$fine';
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)